# CollectionView: EmptyView content not shown

Tags: xamarin.forms, maui

I have a bug in the page display using a listview so I started migrating from listview to collectionview.
This is the XAML code with the collection View. I don't know why when the ItemSource doesn't have any data. The empty view is not shown.

```
<StackLayout Style="{StaticResource PageLayout}">
        <StackLayout VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" IsVisible="{Binding LoadingIndicator}">
            <ActivityIndicator IsRunning="True" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
        </StackLayout>
        <StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" IsVisible="{Binding ShowContent}">
            <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" SelectionMode="Single" SelectionChanged="CollectionView_SelectionChanged" Style="{StaticResource CollectionViewChecklistDefault}">
                <CollectionView.Header>
                    <StackLayout HeightRequest="5">
                    </StackLayout>
                </CollectionView.Header>
                <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid ColumnSpacing="0" RowSpacing="0" Margin="0" Padding="0">
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                    <RowDefinition Height="25" />
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                    <RowDefinition Height="40" />
                                    <RowDefinition Height="10" />
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="37*" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="33*" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="30*" />
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding APP_ID}" IsVisible="False"/>
                                <BoxView Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.RowSpan="8" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Style="{StaticResource ListBox}"/>
                                <Image Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Aspect="AspectFit" Style="{StaticResource ListImage}">
                                    <Image.Source>
                                        <FontImageSource Glyph="&#xf46d;" FontFamily="FontAwesomeSolid" Color="#343a40"></FontImageSource>
                                    </Image.Source>
                                </Image>
                                <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Text="{Binding OBSERVATION_TYPE_NAME}" Style="{StaticResource ListLabelBold}"/>
                                <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Style="{StaticResource PreviewLabel}">
                                    <Label.FormattedText>
                                        <FormattedString>
                                        <Span Text="{Binding Traductions[DATE], Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type viewModel:ObservationCloseListViewModel}}, StringFormat='\{0}:'}"  FontAttributes="Bold" TextTransform="Uppercase" TextColor="DarkGray"/>
                                            <Span Text="{Binding OBSERVATION_DATE, StringFormat=' \{0:dd MMM yyyy}'}"/>
                                        </FormattedString>
                                    </Label.FormattedText>
                                </Label>
                                <Label Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Style="{StaticResource PreviewLabel}">
                                    <Label.FormattedText>
                                        <FormattedString>
                                        <Span Text="{Binding Traductions[COMPANY], Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type viewModel:ObservationCloseListViewModel}}, StringFormat='\{0}:  '}"  FontAttributes="Bold" TextTransform="Uppercase" TextColor="DarkGray"/>
                                            <Span Text="{Binding COMPANY_NAME, StringFormat=' \{0}'}"/>
                                        </FormattedString>
                                    </Label.FormattedText>
                                </Label>
                                <Label Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Style="{StaticResource PreviewLabel}">
                                    <Label.FormattedText>
                                        <FormattedString>
                                            <Span Text="{Binding Traductions[WORKPLACE], Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type viewModel:ObservationCloseListViewModel}}, StringFormat='\{0}:  '}"  FontAttributes="Bold" TextTransform="Uppercase" TextColor="DarkGray"/>
                                            <Span Text="{Binding WORKPLACE_NAME, StringFormat=' \{0}'}"/>
                                        </FormattedString>
                                    </Label.FormattedText>
                                </Label>

                                <Label Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Style="{StaticResource PreviewLabel}">
                                    <Label.FormattedText>
                                        <FormattedString>
                                            <Span Text="{Binding Traductions[SECTOR], Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type viewModel:ObservationCloseListViewModel}}, StringFormat='\{0}:  '}"  FontAttributes="Bold" TextTransform="Uppercase" TextColor="DarkGray"/>
                                            <Span Text="{Binding SECTOR_NAME, StringFormat=' \{0}'}"/>
                                        </FormattedString>
                                    </Label.FormattedText>
                                </Label>

                                <Label Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Style="{StaticResource PreviewLabel}">
                                    <Label.FormattedText>
                                        <FormattedString>
                                            <Span Text="{Binding Traductions[FOLLOW_UP_DEPARTMENT], Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type viewModel:ObservationCloseListViewModel}}, StringFormat='\{0}:  '}"  FontAttributes="Bold" TextTransform="Uppercase" TextColor="DarkGray"/>
                                            <Span Text="{Binding FOLLOW_DEPARTMENT_NAME, StringFormat=' \{0}'}"/>
                                        </FormattedString>
                                    </Label.FormattedText>
                                </Label>
                                <Label Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Style="{StaticResource PreviewLabel}">
                                    <Label.FormattedText>
                                        <FormattedString>
                                            <Span Text="{Binding Traductions[DESCRIPTION], Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type viewModel:ObservationCloseListViewModel}}, StringFormat='\{0}:  '}"  FontAttributes="Bold" TextTransform="Uppercase" TextColor="DarkGray"/>
                                            <Span Text="{Binding OBSERVATION_DESCRIPTION, StringFormat=' \{0}'}"/>
                                        </FormattedString>
                                    </Label.FormattedText>
                                </Label>
                                <Label Grid.Row="7" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3"  Text="{Binding Traductions[CLOSE_OBSERVATION], Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type viewModel:ObservationCloseListViewModel}}}" Style="{StaticResource ListValueGreenEnd}" />
                                <Image Grid.Row="7" Grid.Column="2" Aspect="AspectFit" Style="{StaticResource ListImageArrow}">
                                    <Image.Source>
                                        <FontImageSource Glyph="&#xf138;" FontFamily="FontAwesomeSolid" Color="#7ca04b"></FontImageSource>
                                    </Image.Source>
                                </Image>
                            </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <CollectionView.EmptyView>
                        <StackLayout VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
                            <Label Text="{Binding Traductions[THERE_ARE_NO_OBSERVATIONS], Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type viewModel:ObservationCloseListViewModel}}}" Style="{StaticResource ListNotItemsFound}"/>
                            <Label Text="TEST"/>
                        </StackLayout>
                </CollectionView.EmptyView>
            </CollectionView>
        </StackLayout>
    </StackLayout>
```

This is how it shows with collection view (empty). I put an extra label with TEST.
[image]

This is how it has to be.
[image]

Comment: What is the bindingContext in your code behind?  Have you set the bindingContext with your viewmodel?

Comment: Hi, yes, this was working very well before with the listview, so maybe is not there the problem. 
In the page source I have:
ObservationCloseListViewModel ViewModel = new ObservationCloseListViewModel();

And in the constructor I assign the viewmodel
        public ObservationCloseListPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            BindingContext = ViewModel;
        }

Comment: For testing purposes, consider simplifying the page down to the bare minimum to test this symptom. For example, the collectionview is inside a stacklayout which has `IsVisible="{Binding ShowContent}"`. If you DELETE that (or replace it with `IsVisible="True"`), does it become visible? ALSO, you have verified that the items show correctly when the list is not empty? Does VS Output pane contain any relevant errors or warnings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The root cause of the issue you faced lays in usage of `CollectionView.Header`. But that's not your mistake. It is a bug of `CollectionView`: `EmptyView` does not appear when `Header` is used.
It had been already reported to Xamarin.Forms developers. You can track the progress [here](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/12065).

Comment: Hi @ElifasTeQ , well you are right I test it without the header and it works, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I did some experiments. The only way I can get this symptom to happen is if `{Binding ShowContent}` fails to return True.

I believe the problem isn't the CollectionView. Its the visibility of the surrounding StackLayout.

To verify:

- Replace `IsVisible="{Binding ShowContent}"` with `IsVisible="True"`.

---

If that makes EmptyView show up, then check these possible causes:

- BindingContext. (In a comment, you show what looks like correct code. Double-check.)
- Proper declaration of ShowContent, to inform XAML of changes:

```
    // Start "true", so InitializeComponent will begin with it there.
    private bool _showContent = true;
    public bool ShowContent {
        get => _showContent;
        set {
            _showContent = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
```

- If you have code that sets `ShowContent`, verify that you have set it to `true`.

Answer (score 0):

As for me, it started working when I stopped using the sub-tag `<CollectionView.EmptyView>` and started using the `EmptyView=` attribute for the `<CollectionView>` tag.